# Unittest: assert right SystemExit code

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am using [unittest](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html) to assert that my script raises the right `SystemExit` code.

Based on the example from http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as cm:
    do_something()

the_exception = cm.exception
self.assertEqual(the_exception.error_code, 3)
```

I coded this:

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
    do_something()

the_exception = cm.exception
self.assertEqual(the_exception.error_code, 3)
```

However, this does not work. The following **error** comes up:

```
AttributeError: 'SystemExit' object has no attribute 'error_code'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for a unit test to assert that a method calls sys.exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672151/is-it-possible-for-a-unit-test-to-assert-that-a-method-calls-sys-exit)

Comment: It's the other way: the other question is the duplicate since it was posted in 2013, this question was asked and answered in 2012

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[SystemExit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) derives directly from BaseException and not StandardError, thus it does not have the attribute `error_code`.

Instead of `error_code` you have to use the attribute `code`. The example would look like this:

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
    do_something()

the_exception = cm.exception
self.assertEqual(the_exception.code, 3)
```