# Is it possible for a unit test to assert that a method calls sys.exit()?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a Python 2.7 method that sometimes calls

```
sys.exit(1)
```

Is it possible to make a unit test that verifies this line of code is called when the right conditions are met?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unittest: assert right SystemExit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491724/unittest-assert-right-systemexit-code)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Yes. `sys.exit` raises `SystemExit`, so you can check it with [`assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
    your_method()
```

Instances of `SystemExit` have an attribute `code` which is set to the proposed exit status, and the context manager returned by `assertRaises` has the caught exception instance as `exception`, so checking the exit status is easy:

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
    your_method()

self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
```

[sys.exit Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the `SystemExit` exception ... it is possible to intercept the exit attempt at an outer level.

Comment: +1, except that if he wants to verify that it calls `sys.exit(1)` (as opposed to, say, `sys.exit(0)`) you need to actually assert its `code` is 1. I guess you could do that with `assertRaisesRegexp(SystemExit, '1')`?

Comment: I was sure there was a `unittest` method that lets you pass an exception and a _callable predicate_ to run on the exception or its args, rather than just a _regex pattern_ to run on the string representation of its first arg… but I guess not. Is there some other test module I'm thinking of?

Comment: +1, as for checking error code it's far simpler to do just:

`self.assertRaisesRegex( SystemExit, '^2$', testMethod )`

Less code, readable enough.

Comment: @MarekLewandowski - typo. Must be `self.assertRaisesRegexp`

Answer (score 18):

Here's a complete working example. In spite of [Pavel's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672151/is-it-possible-for-a-unit-test-to-assert-that-a-method-calls-sys-exit/15672165#15672165), it took me a while to figure this out, so I'm including it here in the hope that it will be helpful.

```
import unittest
from glf.logtype.grinder.mapping_reader import MapReader

INCOMPLETE_MAPPING_FILE="test/data/incomplete.http.mapping"

class TestMapReader(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_tx_names_incomplete_mapping_file(self):
        map_reader = MapReader()
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
            tx_names = map_reader.get_tx_names(INCOMPLETE_MAPPING_FILE)
        self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer to your question in the [Python Unit Testing documentation](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/pyunit.html) search for "Testing for Exceptions".  Using your example, the unit test would look like the following:

```
self.assertRaises(SystemExit, your_function, argument 1, argument 2)
```

Remember to include all arguments needed to test your function.

Answer (score 4):

As an additional note to [Pavel's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672151/is-it-possible-for-a-unit-test-to-assert-that-a-method-calls-sys-exit/15672165#15672165), you can also check for specific statuses if they're provided in the function you're testing. For example, if `your_method()` contained the following `sys.exit("Error")`, it would be possible to test for "Error" specifically:

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
    your_method()
    self.assertEqual(cm.exception, "Error")
```