# Python unit testing: change exit code

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm using the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) framework and am making a Python script which should imitate the [Nagios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) script behavior. So I need it to have exit status 0 when all test passed. And 2 (meaning critical) in case one of the tests fails.

The code is similar to the example code in the documentation:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

def test_upper(self):
    self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

def test_isupper(self):
    self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
    self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

def test_split(self):
    s = 'hello world'
    self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
    # Check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Here it writes OK and outputs 0 as exit code. And FAILED (failures=..) and 1 as the exit code.

I would like to place my own string in the output in both these two cases and return 2 in case of failure as the exit code. What should I add here?

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Is it possible for a unit test to assert that a method calls sys.exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672151)*