# How to create a unittest from a function that prints a message and closes the program?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following function that prints an error message and closes the program:

```
def show_error_message(error_message):
    print(error_message)
    sys.exit()  # Close Program
```

Now I'm creating the unittest and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672151/is-it-possible-for-a-unit-test-to-assert-that-a-method-calls-sys-exit) about testing the `sys.exit()` but it doesn't work. I suppose that it's because it prints before closing the message.

How can I test this? Is there something in Python Standard Library that I can use anytime in my project to do the same thing as this function?

What I tried to test was like this:

```
    def test_function_runs(self):
        """Basic smoke test: does the function run."""
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
            show_error_message('message')
        self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
```

The erro I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".test_dynamic_message.py", line 14, in test_function_runs
self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
AssertionError: None != 1
```

I'm still new to python so I hope someone could help me.
Thank you

Comment: Per https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit, the SystemExit exception doesn't have a `message` attribute, only a `code` attribute.

Comment: Which you can also see by calling `str(exception)` where `exception` is your `SystemExit` exception.

Comment: So just replace your `exception.message` with `exception.code`.

Comment: You are right! Thank you so much. I read the link and it totally cleared for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit)

> If the value is an integer, it specifies the system exit status (passed
> to C’s exit() function); if it is None, the exit status is zero; if it
> has another type (such as a string), the object’s value is printed and
> the exit status is one.

The function you're testing exits with a default exit code of 0.
Your test assumes the exit code in the exception will be 1, when you should expect it to be `None` per the documentation.

Comment: I tried to compare with `None` and gave me the same error but saying that `None != None` ... :/

Comment: Well that makes no sense, obviously. Can you show me the stacktrace?

Comment: Hey Charles, I don't know why now it just keeps showing the `message != None` only. But the link you gave about the exception really helped so I was able to understand and fix my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's the code that is wrong.  **Your test is correct and needs no changes**.

What you have exits with success (return code 0):

```
def show_error_message(error_message):
    print(error_message)
    sys.exit()  # Close Program
```

To print the error message to stderr and exit with failure (return code 1) you want this:

```
def show_error_message_and_quit(error_message):
    sys.exit(error_message)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but the test didn't work. I edited the post with the errors. Would love if you could help :)

Comment: Now you've changed the test to check the message instead of checking the return code.  It's a completely different question now.  Don't do that, just ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new here but I will do it next time. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The attributes of exception could be code, message, args and more.

```
class TestExit(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sys_exit_exception(self):
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as e:
            sys.exit('exit_with_err')
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(e.exception, SystemExit))
        self.assertEqual(e.exception.code, 'exit_with_err')
        self.assertEqual(e.exception.message, 'exit_with_err')
        self.assertEqual(e.exception.args, ('exit_with_err',))


    def test_show_error_msg_exception(self):
        # Test the exception type
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as e:
            show_error_message('test but not mock exit')
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(e.exception, SystemExit))
```

Comment: I don't think you understand how `self.assertRaises` works.  Your assertions are skipped.

Comment: You are right, the extra 4 spaces made it out of the scope, I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it changing the code to the one @wim said but only one worked. I edited the post with the errors. Would love if you could help :)